# Reduce footer space

Tags: spacing, header-footer

I am having trouble reducing the footer space. I have a list of contents that is printing below the page number appearing in the footer. How do I solve this issue? I tried setting the footskip length but it didn't work.

Comment: What class are you using? Can you give a minimal working example?

Answer (score 9):

The parameter for setting the distance of the text block from the footnotes is called in a peculiar way: `\skip\footins` (the LaTeX kernel doesn't provide a symbolic name as for the others).

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6cm,paperheight=4cm]{geometry}

%\setlength{\skip\footins}{1cm}

\begin{document}

Some text\footnote{A footnote} to go all the way to the end of this short page and show the
distance from the footnotes. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

\end{document}
```

The two pages with the commented setting:

[image]

The two pages with the uncommented setting:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You should provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

As for question, `\footskip` should be the distance from the bottom of the last line of text to the top of the foot.

`\footheight` is the height of the foot box, and will probably be more useful for what you want to achieve.

Also take a look at the [`fancyhdr`](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/fancyhdr.html) package. Even you decide not to use it, it explains page elements nicely at the very beggining.

Comment: `\footskip` is the dimension used as the baselineskip in the footer. The distance between the bottom of the text block and the top of the footer is `\skip\footins`.

Comment: @egreg: Would you mind adding that as an answer, showing how the space can be reduced?